Unable to Scroll in Mobile Flutter Version : 2.5.3
My code is for Mobile as well as for Web. So, the issue is Unable to Scroll in Mobile but in web working.
I'm using Flutter Version 2.5.3
Here is code snippet
I tried this below Code by Using two List Outer List is for Horizontal scrolling and Inner List for Vertical Scrolling. In Horizontal Scrolling, I need to horizontal scroll multiple dates and vertical Scrolling for Slots of Particular date
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Dummy ListView with SingleChildScrollView'),
    leading: GestureDetector(
      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _showScreen = false;
        });
      },
     ),
    ),

    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: datesDummy.map((date) {
      return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            DateFormat("MMM d, EEEE").format(DateTime.parse(date)),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 300,
            width: 150, // Adjust width as needed
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: slotsByDateDummy[date].length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final slot = slotsByDateDummy[date][index];
                final formattedTime = DateFormat("h:mm a")
                    .format(DateTime.parse(slot["apptStartDateTime"]));

                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ChoiceChip(
                    label: Text(formattedTime),
                    selected: false,
                    onSelected: (_) {},
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
),
),
);      

final List<String> datesDummy = ["2023-08-13", "2023-08-14", "2023-08-15"];

final Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> slotsByDateDummy = {
 "2023-08-13": [
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T11:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-13T12:00:00"},
],
"2023-08-14": [
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-14T10:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-14T11:00:00"},
],
"2023-08-15": [
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-15T09:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-15T11:30:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-15T14:00:00"},
  {"apptStartDateTime": "2023-08-15T16:00:00"},
],
};


I have tried your code and its scrolling in mobile. Try to flutter clean and run your code.
